# YouTubePlayer - How to hide/encrypt API Key?

Tags: java, security, encryption, android-youtube-api

After doing some research online, I read the most secure way to process a request is to have a server make calls to the API (via php) and then submit the data back to the application as a JSON object.

However in the case of using any of the YouTubePlayer subclasses, the API key needs to be set within the application:

`public abstract void initialize (String developerKey, YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener listener)`

The developer key needs to appear *somewhere* in code. And all of the traditional ways of storing the API key (ie as a private static string variable, in an XML file) aren't effective enough.

**Questions:**

1. Are there any ways to hide an API key even if the APK is decompiled?
2. Is it safe just to have the application make a call to the server, and have the server send the API key back as a JSON object (without storing it)? But can can a malicious interception occur with this situation?

This is not an area of expertise for me, so if anyone can offer suggestions, links, example code, that would be great :) Thank you!

Comment: there is no way in the world to hide api key (not that I know of) completely. but you can make it harder to find. use ndk to store key in C library but remember, C also have debugging tools :)

Comment: @RahulKumar is right. There is not secure way. Everything can be reverse-engineered. Sorry. ;(

Answer (score 0):

I am developing service apps for serve business processes, and found that is the best method to encrypt the api with your key.

I am concatenating mac address + device id as an encryption key